# Json parse with elephantbird in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

I can't get the following data to parse in Pig. It's what the twitter API returns after getting all tweets from a certain user.

source data: (I removed some numbers to not invade on anyone's privacy by accident)

```
[{"created_at":"Sat Nov 01 23:15:45 +0000 2014","id":5286804225,"id_str":"5286864225","text":"@Beace_ your nan makes me laugh with some of the things she comes out with","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":52812992878592,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"522","in_reply_to_user_id":398098,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"3","in_reply_to_screen_name":"Be_","user":{"id":425,"id_str":"42433395","name":"SAINS","screen_name":"sa3","location":"Lincoln","profile_location":null,"description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":92,"friends_count":526,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Mon May 25 16:18:05 +0000 2009","favourites_count":6,"utc_offset":0,"time_zone":"London","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":19,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"EDECE9","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme3\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme3\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/52016\/DGDCj67z_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/526\/DGDCj67z_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/424395\/13743515","profile_link_color":"088253","profile_sidebar_border_color":"D3D2CF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E3E2DE","profile_text_color":"634047","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":1,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"e_","name":"\u2601\ufe0f effy","id":3998,"id_str":"398","indices":[0,15]}],"urls":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"en"}, {another one goes here ....} ]
```

I have tried a lot of things but this is the current code I have:

```
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/cloudera/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/cloudera/elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar';
REGISTER 'hdfs:///user/cloudera/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';

--Load Json
loadJson =  LOAD '/user/cloudera/tweetwall' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader() AS (json:map []);

describe loadJson;

--dump loadJson;

--PARSING JSON
--txt
--a = FOREACH loadJson GENERATE json#'text' AS ParsedInput;

dump loadJson;

c = FOREACH loadJson GENERATE flatten(json#'text') as (m:map[]);
```

If I'm not getting erros, I just get no returns (as in 0 bytes returned after the script is done running)

for instance:

```
success!

Input(s):
Successfully read 0 records (532459 bytes) from: "/user/cloudera/tweetwall"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/temp-988640258/tmp-846532109"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0
```

Comment: Some funny names they chose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. You need to give the root name for your input json
    I added "tweets" as your root name
    {"tweets":[<your input>]}

2. This is nested json, so you need to load your json file with 'nested' option in the loader
```

**input.json**

```
{"tweets":[{"created_at":"Sat Nov 01 23:15:45 +0000 2014","id":5286804225,"id_str":"5286864225","text":"@Beace_ your nan makes me laugh with some of the things she comes out with","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":52812992878592,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"522","in_reply_to_user_id":398098,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"3","in_reply_to_screen_name":"Be_","user":{"id":425,"id_str":"42433395","name":"SAINS","screen_name":"sa3","location":"Lincoln","profile_location":null,"description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":92,"friends_count":526,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Mon May 25 16:18:05 +0000 2009","favourites_count":6,"utc_offset":0,"time_zone":"London","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":19,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"EDECE9","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme3\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme3\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/52016\/DGDCj67z_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/526\/DGDCj67z_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/424395\/13743515","profile_link_color":"088253","profile_sidebar_border_color":"D3D2CF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E3E2DE","profile_text_color":"634047","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":1,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"e_","name":"\u2601\ufe0f effy","id":3998,"id_str":"398","indices":[0,15]}],"urls":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"en"}]}
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER '/tmp/json-simple-1.1.jar';
REGISTER '/tmp/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';
REGISTER '/tmp/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';

loadJson = LOAD 'input.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map []);
B = FOREACH loadJson GENERATE flatten(json#'tweets') as (m:map[]);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(m#'text');
DUMP C;

Output:
(@Beace_ your nan makes me laugh with some of the things she comes out with)
```